# Infinite scroll for-looped blocks

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

let's say for example:

```
for($a=0;$a<100;$a++){
    echo '<div class="post">';
    //content here
    echo '</div>';
}
```

How do I make it display the first 10 posts first then a button to see more posts when reached the bottom page:

[I found this one](http://demos.hycus.com/load-more/) but it's using of mysql if only i can get rid of it.

Comment: Do you want to load all the posts statically, during first page load, and show only the first few, or are you trying to make them load dynamically?

Comment: @socha23 It depends on which is the better of the two options i guess..

Comment: Where are the posts coming from?

Comment: @Harmiih from contents of text files :P

Answer (score 3):

You can also use an infinite scroll script. I used the following jQuery plugin very recently : [jQuery Infinite Ajax Scroll](http://www.fieg.nl/infinite-ajax-scroll-a-jquery-plugin). Basically you paginate your content and supply a 'next' button on each page to the next batch of content. The script will hide the next button and will load the content from each 'next' page as you scroll down. Only drawback is that you need to supply enough content on the first page to make the page scrollable.

Comment: With the latest version of the plugin (>=2.0) the drawback is resolved. The plugin will automatically load the next page if your content is too short to make it scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

If you always have the data in the page and just want to incrementally show more, something like

```
$('.post').hide();
$('#more').click(function(){
    $('.post').filter(':hidden').slice(0,9).show();
});
```

Presuming your show-more button is `id="more"`. The MySQL solution involves incrementally adding content to the page and not just showing content that's always there.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting a offset for the loop and changing the offset on the click of a button?

ie.

```
for($a=0; $a < 10; $a++){
 //Do something here
}
```

Then do some script so that when you click the button, the loop fired next is

```
for($a=10; $a < 20; $a++){
 //Do something here
}
```

then just keep incrementing the offset. (reduce the offset for a back/prev button)